# Import .pyd file in google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, fortran77, f2py

I have some old fortran77 codes, and I convert them into .pyd files using f2py. However, I could import these .pyd files in app engine... So does that mean GAE does not support .pyd file? If so, is there any way to call those fortran77 code when my website is hosted by GAE?How about compiling the fortran 77 code on a Linux machine? 
@Guido van Rossum any official confirmation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So does that mean GAE does not support .pyd file?

That is correct; AppEngine only supports pure-Python modules, nothing compiled whatsoever.

I don't know enough about Fortran/Python interop. to comment on the second question, except to say that you can `open()` files uploaded with your app and evaluate them manually.

Comment: I did. Does that mean there is no way to import .pyd in GAE?